# How to retrieve video information using CKFinder?

Tags: php, ckfinder

I am using CKFinder V3 with PHP Connector, currently I am using `command:send` and `ImageInfo` to [retrieve image information](http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder3-php/class_c_k_source_1_1_c_k_finder_1_1_command_1_1_image_info.html) as width and height at server side, example:

```
this._ckFinder.request('command:send', {
                    name: 'ImageInfo',
                    folder: file.get('folder'),
                    params: { fileName: file.get('name') }
                })...
```

Currently I need to use a similar approach for video, specially I need to retrieve video with/height and I could not find any reference in the doc, I would like to know:

- Does CKFinder PHP Connector support this feature? How to retrieve video dimensions?
- If this feature is not supported, is possible to extend CKFinder at back-end level so it can provide these information? How to call this from JS API? Any tutorial or info?

I am aware that is possible to use HTML5 to get some meta information after a video has been inserted in the [DOM example](https://jsbin.com/haxexupace/edit?html,output). But I rather prefer a server side solution any other ideas is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately CKFinder does not process videos out of the box. In order do that you should develop such thing by your own. This would consist:

1. Server side [custom command](https://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder3-php/howto.html#howto_custom_commands) that will return required information.
2. Client side plugin that will [send custom command](https://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder3/#!/guide/dev_requests-section-sending-command-to-the-server) to the server.

So just add a [plugin](http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder3-php/plugins.html) that will add such custom command on server, ie `VideoInfo`. Then on the client side call it as other commands:

```
finder.request( 'command:send', {
    name: 'VideoInfo',
    folder: file.get( 'folder' ),
    params: {
        fileName: file.get( 'name' )
    }
} ).done( function( response ) {
    // Process the response
} );
```

Also check API docs for ['command:send' request](https://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder3/#!/api/CKFinder.Application-request-command_send).